# MySQL Uncompress issue

Tags: mysql

I am facing issue with MySQL, UNCOMPRESS function.

I have table named as `user` and `user_details` stores **COMPRESS** values. In this case before search for values from the `user_details` i have to **UNCOMPRESS** it.

But issue is after I do  **UNCOMPRESS**, search become ***case-sensetive***.

Like.. e.g

If I tries below sql, it will only search for values which contain **CAPITAL TESTING word** and **ignore small case testing word**

> SELECT * FORM user WHERE UNCOMPRESS(user_details) LIKE '%**TESTING**%'.

I want case-insensitive search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But issue is after I do UNCOMPRESS, search become case-sensetive.

This is [because `COMPRESS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_compress) "Compresses a string and returns the result **as a binary string.**" (emphasis mine)

When you perform a LIKE operation on a binary string, a [binary comparison](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html) will be performed (which is case-sensitive).

You may be able to circumvent this by putting a [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) around the `COMPRESS()` statement.

But you probably shouldn't be doing this in the first place. It's an *extremely* inefficient way to search through huge amounts of data. MySQL will have to uncompress *every* row for this operation, and has no chance of using any of its internal optimization methods like indexes.

Don't use `COMPRESS()` in the first place.

Comment: @Poonam you're welcome, but bear in mind this is really, really inefficient. I would get rid of the COMPRESS()

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE LOWER(UNCOMPRESS(user_details)) LIKE '%testing%'
```

But as *Pekka* well pointed or its very inefficient . If your using MyIsam  Engine another alternative is [myisampack](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisampack.html) which compresses the hole table and its still query-able.

Comment: It was a miss spell in the query `FORM` -> `FROM` try now pls